# pushing a value to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to push one more value id to the content value.

I want to add Photo id

```
$id=$comment_fet['ID'];`
```

to content value

```
$content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
```

Now

```
$content="{
"name": "ghggh",
"commentuser": "jghjhgjghj",
"content_type": "alb_comment",
"website_id": "571710720",
"id": 86,
"nodes": [],
"date": "2015-12-14T06:39:25.921Z",
"displayDate": "Mon Dec 14 2015 12:09:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"Like": 0,
"Unlike": 0,
"rating": 0,
"reportAbuse": 0
}"    

function get_album_comment($prefix) {
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
// print_r($request);
$id = $request->photoid;
  $sql = "select * from user_comment where SUB_ID='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or sqlerrorhandler("(" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error(), $sql, __LINE__);
//$datas = array();
while ($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
     $id=$comment_fet['ID'];
    $datas[] = json_decode($content);

  }
echo $get_like = json_encode($datas);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just decode it, append the value and encode it again?

Comment: can you plz show sample how to do it

Comment: @user3386779 What is the content of `$comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];`? Is it a json string?

Comment: ya it is json string

Comment: @user3386779 Do you want to push a new value(say `photo_id`) or replace the existing value of `id` in the json string?

Comment: I want to push new value photoid

Comment: @user3386779 See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$temp=json_decode($content); // decodes it to json
$temp->id=$comment_fet['ID']; // appends photo id to it
$content=json_encode($temp); // encodes it back
?>
```

Comment: still having problem value is not pushed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a new value(say `photo_id`) to the json string, then you can do something like this:

```
// your code

$comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
$id=$comment_fet['ID'];
$datas = json_decode($content, true);
$datas['photo_id'] = $id;
$content=json_encode($datas);

// your code
```

**Sidenote:** Please don't use the `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and were removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

**Edited:**

```
// your code

$contents = array(); // $contents array will contain all contents

while($comment_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $content = $comment_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $id=$comment_fet['ID'];
    $datas = json_decode($content, true);
    $datas['photo_id'] = $id;
    $contents[] = json_encode($datas);
}

// loop through the $contents array to display all contents
for($i = 0; $i < count($contents); ++$i){
    echo $contents[$i] . "<br />";
}

// your code
```

Comment: This will return only one comment

Comment: @user3386779 You can use `while` loop for that. But how would you use the final encoded json string outside `while` loop. I'll update my answer according to that.

Comment: @user3386779 Did you loop through the `$contents` array to display it's contents?

Comment: ya I did it and echo $contents but doen't return

Comment: @user3386779 `$contents` is an array, not a string. Use `for` loop to loop through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97835/discussion-between-user3386779-and-rajdeep-paul).